# Weird behavior in Ncrack

Tags: nmap

I am new with Ncrack, I have a SIP device GXW-4008 I haven't changed the default password, so I wanted to know how long it would take to ncrack to figure it out. I used the following:

```
ncrack 192.168.1.44:23 --user root -P top50000.pwd -d10 --passwords-first
```

But something weird is happening, first of all, the default password is "admin" so it shouldn't take that long, but is taking too long. Second I am using `-d10` because is the highest logging level, and I see that ncrack is always trying the same passwords: abc123, iloveyou, princess, password, 12345, 1234567, 12345678 and 123456789, and repeat those passwords all over again and again, without trying other ones, or at least those are the ones that appear in the log.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean to test port 23? Is there authentication there? Does it crack it at all, or what do you mean by "too long"? Is `admin` in the password file you are using? We need more details to help with this troubleshooting process.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make things clear:

It is about cracking an access via telnet (port 23) and not via SIP (port 5060).

`-P top50000.pwd` takes the file `top50000.pwd` from the ncrack directory (e.g. `/usr/share/ncrack/top50000.pwd`).

Because `-f` is not set it continues in the password file even if a hit was already found.

I assume `--passwords-first` is misspelled by mistake. But it has no effect at this point anyway, because only one user was specified.

The string "admin" is in the file `top50000.pwd` somewhere after the 10000th position:

[image: position of string admin in top50000]

Furthermore, an attack against telnet is rather slow:

[image: Speed againt telnet]
https://nmap.org/ncrack/man.html

As a reference for GXW-4008 login I have consulted the following manual:

https://www.192-168-1-1-ip.co/router/grandstream/gxw4008/6596/

which states:

[image: GXW Login]

The default username here is blank and not root.
And this concerns HTTP and not Telnet.

This means the attack must take longer at this point due to the position of the string. Try pressing enter, then it will display current results.

To get a solution for `ncrack`:

1. Maybe the management interface via telnet does not have the same password set as the default "admin" via HTTP? I couldn't get that from the documentation now.
2. Likewise maybe the given username "root" is wrong?
3. Is the file `top50000.pwd` been edited? one explanation why accordingly the addressed entries are repeated?

If changing user and password does not work - it could be that it does not work altogether:
The HTTP login seems not to be Basic or Digest Authentication which is only supported by ncrack, so it could be that you have to use another tool (for example [Portswigger Burp](https://portswigger.net/support/using-burp-to-brute-force-a-login-page)).

Comment: You are making a lot of assumptions here that should be asked of the OP before jumping into a conclusion.

Comment: True that. I tried to modify it.